# Unable to upload CSV file to blob storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, blob

In ASP.NET web api project I am using following code to upload file to blob storage. This code works for XLS file but gives issue for CSV file.

I am getting following error for CSV: `using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream()) is giving me "cannot access a disposed object" error`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class BlobController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
    {
        try
        {
            if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
            {
                return BadRequest("No file selected.");
            }
        // Retrieve the connection string from your configuration or secure storage.
        string connectionString = "your_connection_string_here";

        // Create a reference to the Blob storage client.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Get a reference to the container where you want to upload the file.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("your_container_name_here");

        // Create the container if it doesn't exist.
        await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

        // Generate a unique name for the file to be uploaded.
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

        // Read the file content into a memory buffer.
        byte[] fileBytes;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
            fileBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }

        // Upload the file to Azure Blob Storage using the memory buffer.
        await blockBlob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);

        return Ok("File uploaded successfully.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, $"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching out and reporting this issue.

I see that you are making use of `Microsoft.Azure.Storage` package which is now deprecated. This is a [migration guide](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/AzureStorageNetMigrationV12.md) for upgrading guidance. More info [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob/).

So please try using [Azure.Storage.Blobs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs/) package instead and check if that helps. Your above sample can be modified like below and see if that helps to upload the csv successfully.

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;

namespace StorageFileStream.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : ApiController
    {
        [System.Web.Mvc.Route("api/Home")]
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadFile()
        {
            

            try
            {

                if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
                {
                    return BadRequest("Multipart data not received.");
                }

                var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"));
                await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

                if (provider.FileData.Count == 0)
                {
                    return BadRequest("No file selected.");
                }

                var fileData = provider.FileData[0];
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileData.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('"'));

                // Create a BlobServiceClient object by using the connection string.
                BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("XXXXXXXXXX MY Connection String XXXXXXXXX");

                // Get a reference to the container where you want to upload the file.
                BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(_containerName);

                // Create the container if it doesn't exist.
                await containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

                // Get a reference to the blob.
                BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);

                // Upload the file to Azure Blob Storage.
                using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(fileData.LocalFileName))
                {
                    await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, true); // Set "true" to overwrite if the blob already exists
                }

                // Cleanup the local file created during the upload
                File.Delete(fileData.LocalFileName);

                return Ok("File uploaded successfully.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return InternalServerError(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to invoke this Web APi from the postman, with request headers sent as `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` and I got the 200 success code. See below:

[image]

I also confirmed that the csv file was uploaded to the storage container.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou for the response. I have switched the package. But I am still getting `cannot access a disposed object` error with the code you shared. it has nothing to do with Blob Storage, its just that streaming is not working,

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I have edited my above comment and provided more details and updated the sample code. Could you please test with that and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. My issue has more to do with how to get rid of `using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream()) is giving me "cannot access a disposed object"` error and less to do with how to upload file to blob storage. I see two issues with your solution, 1) You are not using `IFormFile` to get file. 2) I am using .net core 6.0 framework and I dont have access to `Request.Content`